# TryParse: What is more readable?

Tags: c#

Out style:

```
bool result;
if(something.TryParse(val, out result))
{
    DoSomething(result);
}
```

Nullable style:

```
bool? result = something.TryParse2(val);
if(result.HasValue)
{
    DoSomething(result.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

TryParse(val, out result) is a idiom established by the .NET framework in int.TryParse, DateTime.TryParse, etc. It is likely that people that read the code will be familiar with this idiom, so you should stick to it, unless you find a very good reason not to.

Comment: Not exactly my preferred option but given the unprecise nature of the question I'll grant the answer =) The established idiom argument is very good.

Comment: It was an idiom established before the addition of nullabes, though. Microsoft has also broken consistency when a better feature was added, for instance the inconsistant use of FooCollection and Collection<Foo> or FooEventArgs and EventArgs<Foo>.

Answer (score 4):

I don't mean to be unkind.  But when you propose a change to a well-established idiom, it undermines confidence if your sample code isn't right.

Your first example should either be:

```
something result;
if (something.TryParse(val, out result))
{
   DoSomething(result);
}
```

or:

```
bool result;
if (bool.TryParse(value, out result))
{
    DoSomething(result);
}
```

Your second example should either be:

```
Nullable<something> result = something.TryParse2(val);
if(result.HasValue)
{
    DoSomething(result.Value);
}
```

or:

```
bool? result = bool.TryParse2(val);
if (result.HasValue)
{
   DoSomething(result);
}
```

If I *were* going to implement an extension method for each value type that did what your `TryParse2` seems to do, I wouldn't call it `TryParse2`.  Right now, if a method's name begins with `Try`, we expect it to return a `bool` indicating whether or not it succeeded or failed.  Creating this new method creates a world where that expectation is no longer valid.  And before you dismiss this, think about what was going through your mind when you wrote example code that didn't work, and why you were so sure that `result` needed to be a `bool`.

The other thing about your proposal is that it seems to be trying to solve the wrong problem.  If I found myself writing a lot of `TryParse` blocks, the first question I'd ask isn't "How can I do this in fewer lines of code?"  I'd ask, "Why do I have parsing code scattered throughout my application?"  My first instinct would be to come up with a higher level of abstraction for what I'm really trying to do when I'm duplicating all of that `TryParse` code.

Comment: Good point. Naming the nullable method something more suitable (especially something that isn't already "taken") would come across more clearly. I assume you know you can't put extension methods on the type, only instances.

Comment: You implement extension methods *for* a type, and you implement them *in* a static class method that takes an instance of that type as its argument.

Answer (score 2):

I think out style is more readable in general. People are less familiar with nullable types (just check the amount of questions about them here), and they'll be even less familiar with a TryParse2 which does not exist in the standard library (or however it's technically called in .NET).

Comment: Would you reconsider if it were 10 years ago and C# 1.0 had had nullables and you were to choose?

Comment: Probably, if back then there was a null returning tryparse as well. But now is not 10 years ago.

Comment: I think that other developers' unfamiliarity with core language features is something that needs a fix, not a workaround.

Comment: And certainly the fix is going wild and writing code for which established idioms already exist.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use the second example.  Although I see both as perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

A nullable type has a Value property which is not nullable of the same type.  This is where you do not need to convert a nullable type but rather use the value of the nullable type.

Comment: It's best to add these comments as, well, comments on the answer you are commenting to

Comment: True, but that requires 50 rep.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the out variable syntax used in many applications.

Personally I like it too.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the second example because it's a more type inference friendly style of programming.  Having an out parameter prevents a developer from using type inference for a particular call.

```
var result = Int32.TryParse("123");
```

Answer (score 0):

I find both examples to be clunky.

I'd choose the `TryParse` because it's an idiom that already exists in the .NET Framework.

Comment: Interesting. Is it just the examples or do you have an alternative solution?

Comment: It's not your examples that are clunky: you've done as well as you can do, given the circumstances.  It's a limitation of the language. I don't know how I'd change it, though.